# Issue with Undefined method in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building an app in Rails. I have a table called "Users" and a table called "Profiles." Each user has_one profile. Each profile belongs_to a user. I am trying to work with the index page of the profile_controller. I want to have each users profile display in the order they signed in. But I am having more basic issues. To start, I have

```
 @users = All.users
```

defined in the index action. Each "profile" has a "name" property. In the index view, I attempt to access this property through @users

```
  <% @users.each do |u| %>
    <%= u.profile.name %> 
  <% end %>
```

This brings up this error "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass." Note, this does work:

```
 <% @users.each do |u| %>
    <%= u.last_sign_in_at %> 
  <% end %>
```

I want to organize the names by the "last_sign_in_at" Devise property in "Users," otherwise I would simply use the profile object directly. I haven't started the ordering yet. Can someone help? I want to be able to access profile properties through the @users instance variable. Here is my schema:

```
create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
t.integer  "age"
t.string   "status"
t.string   "location"
t.string   "bio"
t.string   "primary_instrument"
t.string   "second_instrument"
t.string   "third_instrument"
t.string   "name"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "looking_for"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you show us also User and Profile models?
Errors appears because one or more users do not have profile, you can also use methods like `u.profile.try(:name)` or (worst in my opinion) `u.profile.name if user.profile.present?`

And about user - profile properties , here is greate article about this topic [delegate](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/rails-delegates-are-even-more-useful-than-i-knew), or if you do not want to use this you can do something like

```
#user Model
def name
  profile.try(:name)
end
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Yes, the issue was some Users did not have profiles.